# GraphQL x MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, graphql, graphql-js

I'm trying to read some data from a **mongodb** database with **graphql** and **mongoose** but everytime I query the db it returns `null` but no error is thrown.
Here's the code:

```
// Controller.js
exports.user_read = function(id) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    Contact.findById(id, function(err, user) {
      err ? reject(err) : resolve(user);
    }
  });
}

// Resolver.js
var contact = require('Controller');
...
// root object passed as rootValue to graphqlHTTP
getUser: ({ id }) => { 
  contact.user_read(id)
}
...
```

Any tips and help would be appreciated.
P.S. This also seems to be happening with all my queries which take the same `Promise` format in the `controller.js` file.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with the code you've provided, except that you don't need to wrap `Contact.findById` in a new Promise -- it should already return a promise as long as you omit the callback. Either way that shouldn't be a problem. If you can get the data you need with a call to findById **outside** GraphQL, then the problem is probably with your GraphQL setup and you should post your full schema and root object. If you can't get findById to return anything, even outside any resolver, you'll want to include your Contact model and how you're connecting to your database.

Answer (score 1):

You need to `await contact.user_read(id)`. Without the await, you are simply sending back a Promise. It's most likely pending when it is returned, therefore the `null` return.

Including Daniel Rearden's suggestion to get rid of the extra Promise, here's what your code would look like:

```
// Controller.js
exports.user_read = async id => {
  return Contact.findById(id, (err, user) => {
      err ? reject(err) : resolve(user);
  });
}

// Resolver.js
var contact = require('Controller');
...
// root object passed as rootValue to graphqlHTTP
getUser: ({ id }) => { 
  return await contact.user_read(id)
}
...
```